# Xcode build running on device but failing on simultor

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I'm using CocoaPods with a React Native app. I've had various errors when running builds in the Xcode simulator. I don't have issues running it on my device. Here's one that I get when I have breakpoints enabled:

```
- (void)ensureOnJavaScriptThread:(dispatch_block_t)block
    {
      RCTAssert(_jsThread, @"This method must not be called before the JS thread is created");
```

The error here is green (yet breaking, thanks Xcode) and it says `com.facebook.react.JavaScript (9): breakpoint 1.2`

I get two errors when I disable breakpoints, this is one:

```
void Instance::loadApplication(std::unique_ptr<RAMBundleRegistry> bundleRegistry,
                                   std::unique_ptr<const JSBigString> string,
                                   std::string sourceURL) {
      callback_->incrementPendingJSCalls();
      SystraceSection s("Instance::loadApplication", "sourceURL",
                        sourceURL);
      nativeToJsBridge_->loadApplication(std::move(bundleRegistry), std::move(string),
                                         std::move(sourceURL));
    }
```

with the red error on the `callback_->` line reading `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)`

the second is this a `signal SIGABRT` error from this code:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) { 
  @autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
  }
}
```

I think i've fixed that issue before by enabling zombies. When I do that, I see this in the console:

```
2018-07-11 16:56:08.326 [info][tid:main][RCTRootView.m:293] Running application Mapp ({
initialProps =     {
};
rootTag = 11;
})
=================================================================
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:]
PID: 34682, TID: 5546845, Thread name: (none), Queue name: com.mixpanel.20e6d2c2b6c431dfecfdfaa100ec0a11.0x7fa94db06940.network, QoS: 0
Backtrace:
4   Mapp                           0x0000000103a31dd9 -[MPNetwork updateNetworkActivityIndicator:] + 121
5   Mapp                           0x0000000103a2ec09 -[MPNetwork flushQueue:endpoint:] + 985
6   Mapp                           0x0000000103a2e7b0 -[MPNetwork flushEventQueue:] + 64
7   Mapp                           0x0000000103a10418 __32-[Mixpanel flushWithCompletion:]_block_invoke + 312
8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e3f47ab _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e3f57ec _dispatch_client_callout + 8
10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e3fdbe5 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 1305
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e3fe4fa _dispatch_queue_invoke + 328
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e3fa344 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 726
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e40136c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 664
14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e401076 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 132
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010e920169 _pthread_wqthread + 1387
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010e91fbe9 start_wqthread + 13
```

This to me is unreadable. I don't understand what's wrong. Reminder: this build runs without breaking errors on my device, even when breakpoints are enabled. Is this something I should worry about? Please help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because in your code `UI API called on a background thread`. So please disable the **Main Thread Checker** of xcode. it will work.

> Edit Scheme --- >  Diagonstics --- > Runtime API Checking ---> Main
>   Thread Checker (un-check this setting)

[image]

> Note: Always update the UI inside below method on a background thread

**Or**

Put your `[UIApplication setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:]` Method inside `DispatchQueue.main.async`

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async { // Correct
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true // in swift 4
       [UIApplication setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:]// in objective-C
 }
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/code_diagnostics/main_thread_checker

Comment: Thanks Mahipal! Once I do that I don't see the error anymore. This is probably still something I need to deal with though, right? Or is it ok since it runs alright on my actual device?

Comment: Actually this is add-on of xcode available from xcode 9.0 to track UI API on background while debugging through simulator only.

Comment: So I don't have to fix it because it is working on my device?

Comment: We have two option to fix, either through the settings or using code..both I added in answers...if you fixed through settings..then it's okay, it will not create any problem.